# Vlasmarktdreef in april 2018

Tags: europe, belgium, geek-travel

We have time for the next 2 weeks in Belgium. Can we visit vlasmarktdreef to see and enjoy a walk along the blue bell forests in the month of April. If yes, when exactly will be the best time

Comment: Please define best.

Comment: If one would know about the forest, or even if not, the best time to visit any forest would be around the time when the trees/flowers etc. bloom at their best. I want to know whether I will be able to see the true blue bells in the forest if I visit on 21st-22nd April weekend

Comment: No, don't generalise it. It might be best time for you but not for someone  else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you mean the Hallerbos (Vlasmarktdreef) near Halle, Belgium.
In that case [their site](https://www.hallerbos.be/wanneer-bloeien-hyacinten/bloeiperiode-2018/) will help you out, (if you can read Dutch or use a translating service.)

The last posts I find mentioned that the Bos Hyacinten (the local version of Blue Bells) are out now. Knowing the flowers it is very likely that you can still enjoy them in ten days time but if the weather turns very hot or there are torrential rains you might be out of luck.
In that case going as soon as possible might be better. (Check out the site for updates.)